# What does 33天 mean?

Tags: meaning

I have seen number "33" in some of Chinese drama and novels. I wonder what is the historical meaning behind 33? Especially 33天？

For example, there is a drama named "失恋33天", which has an English title version of "Love is not Blind". However, I couldn't understand the meaning between 33天 still.

Comment: 33 sounds well in Chinese.

Comment: Is there any specific meaning to it?

Comment: The sound of 三 is close to that of 生 (live, life, alive, active). 三三不盡，六六無窮。It means something is alive forever. I do not know the reason why the author chooses 33. But 33 looks like a happy number. The break up ( 失戀) is unhappy.  It looks some dramatic elements in the 33 days after the the unhappy breakup. This is my speculation.

Comment: you cannot really relate the Chinese name and its English name, 33天 just means thirty-three days, no other special meaning in Chinese

Answer (score 3):

This is meaning that the love story occurred in these days.

in 33 days, a story start and end.

Answer (score 2):

I haven't watched the movie, but I know of it. To me, "33 days" sounds like an arbitrary interval and carry no special meaning.